# What is the significance of the falcon in the movie?

Tags: analysis, the-bone-collector

In The Bone Collector (1999), a falcon is shown at the beginning and end of the movie.

[image]

What is the significance of this falcon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The falcon symbolism is two fold:

1 - The falcon symbolises a freedom that Rhymes doesn't possess. He's confined to his bed and utterly dependant on other people.

> In order to illustrate how much Rhyme misses the loss of his freedom, a peregrine falcon is shown in frequent close-ups on the ledge of his apartment. The bird gets to flap his wings and fly away. Rhyme doesn't have that same mobility, as we are constantly reminded.

[IMDB - Source](http://www.imdb.com/reviews/215/21523.html)

2 - The symbolic, totem meaning of a falcon is as follows:

> The Falcon animal totem comes to us when we require higher vision, or higher knowledge in solving current dilemmas in our lives.

and

> The Falcon is a solar emblem for success, victory and rising above a situation.

and

> At its core, the Falcon animal totem represents visionary power, wisdom, and guardianship. This powerful bird awakens visionary power, and leads you to your life purpose. The Falcon carries with it a message of transition and change - perhaps in your vocation, work, career, etc.

[Source - www.whats-your-sign.com](http://www.whats-your-sign.com/falcon-animal-totem.html)

The last point is more relevant to the book as, in the book, Rhymes is intending commiting suicide when the case has been closed.